# Conda: Dependencies missing in current osx-64 channels

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, graphlab

**(*) ISSUE:** I am trying to install GraphLab Create on MacOS for my coursera class. The installer fails when trying to create a new conda environment.

**(*) ATTEMPTED SOLUTIONS:**

(1) Installed packages listed on the error message for the current version of conda with:
./conda install  conda=4.0

(2) Updated conda itself, when I ran the GrapLab installer it DOWNGRADED to 4.0.8

**(*) ERROR MESSAGE:**

```
Did not find a broken "gl-env" environment.

Creating conda environment "gl-env".
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org

Fetching package metadata: 

Solving package specifications: 

Error:  Dependencies missing in current osx-64 channels: 

  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * openblas
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py27_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> numpy 1.11* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py34_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numpy 1.10.4 py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scipy 0.17.0 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> pytables 3.2.2 np110py35_1 -> numexpr 2.5* -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> numexpr 2.5 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py35_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py27_0 -> blas * mkl
  - anaconda 4.0|4.0.0* -> scikit-learn 0.17.1 np110py34_0 -> blas * mkl
```

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

```
anaconda search -t conda blas * mkl
```

(and similarly for the other packages)

**(*) CONDA ENVIRONMENT:**

```
platform : osx-64

conda version : 4.0.8

conda-build version : 0+unknown

python version : 2.7.13.final.0

requests version : 2.9.1

channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64/
            https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch/
            https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64/
            https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch/
config file : None
```

is foreign system : False

**(*) INSTALLED PACKAGE VERSIONS:**

pip 8.1.1

pip list:

```
alabaster (0.7.7)
anaconda-client (1.4.0)
anaconda-navigator (1.1.0)
appnope (0.1.0)
appscript (1.0.1)
argcomplete (1.0.0)
astropy (1.1.2)
Babel (2.2.0)
backports-abc (0.4)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.4.0.2)
beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
bitarray (0.8.1)
blaze (0.9.1)
bokeh (0.11.1)
boto (2.39.0)
Bottleneck (1.0.0)
cdecimal (2.3)
cffi (1.5.2)
chest (0.2.3)
cloudpickle (0.1.1)
clyent (1.2.1)
colorama (0.3.7)
conda (4.0.8)
conda-build (0+unknown)
conda-env (2.4.5)
conda-manager (0.3.1)
configobj (5.0.6)
cryptography (1.3)
cycler (0.10.0)
Cython (0.23.4)
cytoolz (0.7.5)
dask (0.8.1)
datashape (0.5.1)
decorator (4.0.9)
dill (0.2.4)
docutils (0.12)
dynd (0.7.3.dev1)
enum34 (1.1.2)
et-xmlfile (1.0.1)
fastcache (1.0.2)
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Cors (2.1.2)
funcsigs (0.4)
futures (3.0.3)
gevent (1.1.0)
greenlet (0.4.9)
grin (1.2.1)
h5py (2.5.0)
HeapDict (1.0.0)
idna (2.0)
ipaddress (1.0.14)
ipykernel (4.3.1)
ipython (4.1.2)
ipython-genutils (0.1.0)
ipywidgets (4.1.1)
itsdangerous (0.24)
jdcal (1.2)
jedi (0.9.0)
Jinja2 (2.8)
jsonschema (2.4.0)
jupyter (1.0.0)
jupyter-client (4.2.2)
jupyter-console (4.1.1)
jupyter-core (4.1.0)
llvmlite (0.9.0)
locket (0.2.0)
lxml (3.6.0)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
matplotlib (1.5.1)
mistune (0.7.2)
mpmath (0.19)
multipledispatch (0.4.8)
nbconvert (4.1.0)
nbformat (4.0.1)
networkx (1.11)
nltk (3.2)
nose (1.3.7)
notebook (4.1.0)
numba (0.24.0)
numexpr (2.5)
numpy (1.10.4)
odo (0.4.2)
openpyxl (2.3.2)
pandas (0.18.0)
partd (0.3.2)
path.py (0.0.0)
patsy (0.4.0)
pep8 (1.7.0)
pexpect (4.0.1)
pickleshare (0.5)
Pillow (3.1.1)
pip (8.1.1)
ply (3.8)
psutil (4.1.0)
ptyprocess (0.5)
py (1.4.31)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
PyAudio (0.2.7)
pycosat (0.6.1)
pycparser (2.14)
pycrypto (2.6.1)
pycurl (7.19.5.3)
pyflakes (1.1.0)
Pygments (2.1.1)
pyOpenSSL (0.15.1)
pyparsing (2.0.3)
pytest (2.8.5)
python-dateutil (2.5.1)
pytz (2016.2)
PyYAML (3.11)
pyzmq (15.2.0)
QtAwesome (0.3.2)
qtconsole (4.2.0)
QtPy (1.0)
redis (2.10.3)
requests (2.9.1)
rope (0.9.4)
scikit-image (0.12.3)
scikit-learn (0.17.1)
scipy (0.17.0)
setuptools (20.3)
simplegeneric (0.8.1)
singledispatch (3.4.0.3)
six (1.10.0)
snowballstemmer (1.2.1)
sockjs-tornado (1.0.1)
Sphinx (1.3.5)
sphinx-rtd-theme (0.1.9)
spyder (2.3.8)
SQLAlchemy (1.0.12)
statsmodels (0.6.1)
sympy (1.0)
tables (3.2.2)
terminado (0.5)
toolz (0.7.4)
tornado (4.3)
traitlets (4.2.1)
unicodecsv (0.14.1)
Werkzeug (0.11.4)
wheel (0.29.0)
xlrd (0.9.4)
XlsxWriter (0.8.4)
xlwings (0.7.0)
xlwt (1.0.0)
```

I also tried creating the conda environment manually but received the same error, any ideas on the best way to proceed from here?

Comment: Please accept the answer by zhrist as it is always solving the problem described in your answer!

Answer (score 7):

Usually this kind of problems are due to miscompatibility of versions, so the solution would be to update conda before the GraphLab installation:

```
conda update conda
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem, try installing some of those packages within the conda environment.

Running:

```
conda install scikit-learn
conda install scipy
```

accepting the changes to the packages, and then running the original `conda create -n gl-env` command worked for me.